# Getting this error after updating Meteor

Tags: meteor

Ijust updgraded Meteor to the latest version and now when I run my app I get this error

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reove'
>   W20140109-22:53:08.415(-5)? (STDERR)     at server/config.coffee:4:34
>   W20140109-22:53:08.416(-5)? (STDERR)     at
>   app/server/config.coffee.js:29:3 W20140109-22:53:08.416(-5)? (STDERR) 
>   at
>   /Volumes/Dev/Development/projects/pipevine/shingle/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
>   W20140109-22:53:08.416(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
>   W20140109-22:53:08.417(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach
>   (/Volumes/Dev/Users/harjitsingh/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>   W20140109-22:53:08.417(-5)? (STDERR)     at
>   /Volumes/Dev/Development/projects/pipevine/shingle/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5

Comment: Can you list the contents of `server/config.coffee`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misspelled 'remove' in 'server/config.coffee' on line 4.

Comment: Thanks that was it. Had a long day troubleshooting other issues, hence missed it...